Authorization Denied by Plugin Pipelines: --privileged=true Not Allowed for docker buildx on Bitbucket self-hosted Kubernetes runner
I’m running into an issue with Docker Buildx on a Bitbucket self-hosted runner deployed in Kubernetes. My goal is to use Docker Buildx to build and push multi-platform Docker images directly from my Bitbucket pipeline. The Buildx command runs perfectly on my local machine, but on the Kubernetes self-hosted runner, it fails with an authorization error.
Here’s my pipeline configuration:
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Docker build
          runs-on:
            - 'self.hosted'
            - 'linux'
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - echo "Executing on self-hosted runner" 
            - echo "$DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
            - wget https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/v0.18.0/buildx-v0.18.0.linux-amd64
            - chmod +x buildx-v0.18.0.linux-amd64
            - mv buildx-v0.18.0.linux-amd64 docker-buildx
            - mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
            - mv docker-buildx ~/.docker/cli-plugins
            - docker buildx build -t gurgenyegoryan/test-bitbucket:latest --push --platform linux/arm64 . # Build multi-architecture image for the platforms provided and push to Dockerhub

And here is the Kubernetes job (runner)configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: runner-oauth-credentials
      labels:
        accountUuid: *************************
        repositoryUuid: ***********************
        runnerUuid: ****************************
    data:
      oauthClientId: *****************************=
      oauthClientSecret: *********************************************=
  
  - apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: runner
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            accountUuid: *************************
            repositoryUuid: ***********************
            runnerUuid: ****************************
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: runner
              image: docker-public.packages.atlassian.com/sox/atlassian/bitbucket-pipelines-runner
              securityContext:
                privileged: true
              env:
                - name: DOCKER_BUILDKIT
                  value: 0
                - name: ACCOUNT_UUID
                  value: "{*****************}"
                - name: REPOSITORY_UUID
                  value: "{*************************-826239d933d2}"
                - name: RUNNER_UUID
                  value: "{**********************}"
                - name: OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: runner-oauth-credentials
                      key: oauthClientId
                - name: OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: runner-oauth-credentials
                      key: oauthClientSecret
                - name: WORKING_DIRECTORY
                  value: "/tmp"
                - name: RUNTIME_PREREQUISITES_ENABLED
                  value: "true"
              volumeMounts:
                - name: tmp
                  mountPath: /tmp
                - name: docker-containers
                  mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
                  readOnly: true
                - name: var-run
                  mountPath: /var/run
            - name: docker-in-docker
              image: docker:20.10.7-dind
              env:
                - name: DOCKER_BUILDKIT
                  value: "0"
              securityContext:
                privileged: true
              volumeMounts:
                - name: tmp
                  mountPath: /tmp
                - name: docker-containers
                  mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
                - name: var-run
                  mountPath: /var/run
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
            - name: tmp
            - name: docker-containers
            - name: var-run

but I am getting this error:
docker buildx build -t gurgenyegoryan/test-bitbucket:latest --push --platform linux/arm64 . #0 building with "default" instance using docker-container driver #1 [internal] booting buildkit #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 6.0s done #1 creating container buildx_buildkit_default 0.0s done #1 ERROR: Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: --privileged=true is not allowed ------ > [internal] booting buildkit: ------ ERROR: Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: --privileged=true is not allowed
please help find solution. When I run bitbucket runner on vm machine, it work, but in aws eks I have this issue.
Bitbucket runner on Kubernetes

I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?
